# Squarespace: How to make my radio buttons in my form horizontal?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I am doing an RSVP form for my wedding guests on my Squarespace wedding website and want to do a radio button option for the "will you be attending" question. They pick yes or no.

http://www.meetusinthemountains.net/rsvp/

Right now, the radio buttons are vertical/in list form when I would like them to be horizontal to save space. There is no custom option to do this, so I need to do it via the CSS. Every time I try inline the display, it does nothing. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Nice site, and congrats :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `display:inline-block;` CSS property on the radio buttons that you want to be in line.

For your specific example, give the option class `display:inline-block;`

Comment: For some reason when I do this via the inspector, it moves a completely different field in the form and not the radio buttons. Anywhere specific I should be putting it? I've tried numerous things.

Comment: Put it in this selector: `.form-wrapper .field-list .field .option`

Comment: Thank you! I am an idiot and was doing inline-BOX in that area and not block. This worked!

Comment: Great! Wish you luck!

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to give you credit for that haha